# @RequestMapping annotation not working if <context:component-scan /> is in application context instead of dispatcher context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring of version 2.5.6 with <context:component-scan /> and @Autowired.

While I'd been using **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping** in my dispatcher context everything was OK - autowiring was working fine, routes was picking controllers in right way etc.

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="/login/login.html" value-ref="loginController" />
            <entry key="/secured/index/index.html" value-ref="indexController" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then I decided to use **@RequestMapping** insted of configuring my routes in a XML file.

```
@Controller("loginController")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login/login.html")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login/login");
        return model;
    }

}
```

When I had rewritten the code to use **@RequestMapping**, problem started. The server (Tomcat) began to give me a "**No mapping found for HTTP request with URI**" error.

I've found that the solution was to insert an **"<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springwebapp.controller" />"** element in my dispatcher context config.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- ============== -->
    <!-- URL Mapping    -->
    <!-- ============== -->

<!--    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping"> -->
<!--        <property name="urlMap"> -->
<!--            <map> -->
<!--                <entry key="/login/login.html" value-ref="loginController" /> -->
<!--                <entry key="/secured/index/index.html" value-ref="indexController" /> -->
<!--            </map> -->
<!--        </property> -->
<!--    </bean> -->

    <!-- ============ -->
    <!-- viewResolver -->
    <!-- ============ -->

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springwebapp.controller" />

</beans>
```

I feel that this can be a bad solution because I have similar **"<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springwebapp" />"** in my app context config file to handle all other dependencies in one shot.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="./spring-security.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springwebapp" />

</beans>
```

The question is why **<context:component-scan />** at application level isn't picking **@RequestMapping** annotations right? I know that I can limit component scan by **base-package** at app level to certain package, but my intention was to use only one **component-scan** at app level and nothing more. Do I really have to use two distinct **component-scan** elements or maybe I'm missing something?

Here is my **web.xml**:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>SpringWebApp</display-name>

    <!-- ========== -->
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <!-- ========== -->

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/mvc-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/spring/application-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- =============== -->
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!-- =============== -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: can you post your Web.xml ?

Comment: Sure - inserted it at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding this tag to your app context :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**EDIT**

For `Spring 2.5` try by adding the annotation config tag, a `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and a `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` bean to your app context :

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Comment: I found in the documentation that <mvc:annotation-driven /> is available from Spring 3. I tried to add <context:annotation-config /> (available in 2.5) but that helps nothing.

Comment: sorry didn't saw that you were using Spring 2.5

Comment: Adding <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/> (other two tags wasn't required) helped. Thanks! But I don't understand one thing. Here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html they write that I only need to include that tag if I define a custom HandlerMapping otherwise it is included implicitly. This isn't my case, so why do I need to include it explicitly?

Comment: The other weird thing is that I found somewhere on the web that DefaultAnnotationHandlerMa‌​pping should be defined in dispatcher context, but in my case it works only (as you suggested) if it is in the app context.

Comment: You are right, the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMa‌​pping will be included implicitly. But in Spring 2.5, it only work if you have the context:component-scan tag in the mvc-context. Since you want to put the context:component-scan tag only in the app context, you have to declare it explicitly. It's kind of a workaround to make it work without having the context:component-scan tag in both contexts.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answer to my question (many thanks to **Jean-Philippe Bond**) I decided to change my approach. I understood that having two separate **context:component-scan** is the proper way.

Now my **app context** has got:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springwebapp" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" type="annotation"/>
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

and my **dispatcher context** has got:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springwebapp" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```