# Scope of <context:component-scan.../> and <context:property-placeholder.../> in hierarchical contexts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ioc, component-scan, property-placeholder

I have read:

[Multiple component-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21773092/18157)

[What is the difference between ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11708967/18157)

[@RequestMapping annotation not working if <context:component-scan /> is in application context instead of dispatcher context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893772/18157) (more on this one later)

and several others but none of these answers the question:

Why is the scope of `<context:component-scan.../>` limited when it is present in the ROOT context of a Spring MVC application?

My understanding is that it causes scanning of all classes in the specified packages and instantiates any beans stereotyped with `@Component` or any of its sub-stereotypes (`@Repository`, `@Service` and `@Controller`).

Given:

**applicationContext.xml** (root context)

```
<beans...>
    ...
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>
    <context:property-placeholder 
               ignore-resource-not-found="true" 
               location="classpath:default.properties, file:///etc/gallery/gallery.properties"/>
</beans>
```

**main-servlet.xml** (servlet context)

```
<beans ...>
    ...
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/image/**"   location="file:/${gallery.location}" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**"     location="/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**"      location="/js/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**"  location="/images/"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

**com/myproject/web/MainController.java**

```
package com.myproject.web;
@Controller
public class MainController 
{
    ...

    @RequestMapping("/gallery/**")
    public String gallery(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Spring docs state that any beans instantiated in the root context are shared and available to the individual servlet application contexts.  Thus the two `<context:...>` declarations in the root context should result in beans that are visible in the servlet context.  But this does not appear to be the case.  I am required to repeat BOTH `<context:component-scan.../>` and `<context:property-placeholder.../>` in the servlet context.

Omitting the `<context:component-scan.../>` in the servlet context results in

```
Sep 15, 2015 10:08:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/gallery/habitat/20150813] in DispatcherServlet with name 'main'
Sep 15, 2015 10:08:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/error] in DispatcherServlet with name 'main'
```

indicating that the `@Controller` was not resolved.

Omitting the `<context:property-placeholder.../>` results in a `@Value` annotation using a property reference not being processed, which in my case results in some broken links.

Since both these `<context:.../>` directives result in bean instantiations, I'm confused as to why the beans are not visible in the child context, in direct contradiction to the documentation.  Also, doesn't having two `component-scan` statements cause the controller bean to be instantiated twice?

With regards to [@RequestMapping annotation not working if <context:component-scan /> is in application context instead of dispatcher context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893772/18157), I do have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in my app context, and the answers here do not explain WHY two `component-scan` statements are necessary.

I'm really uncomfortable using "magic" unless I completely understand how it works *and can predict how it will behave when I tweak something*.  So the "solution" of "just add it in both places and move on" is unacceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `<context:property-placeholder />`

The `<context:property-placeholder />` registers a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) which is a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`]. The key here is `BeanFactory`, it operates on a `BeanFactory` (the `ApplicationContext` is such a thing). To be precise it operates on the `BeanFactory` it is defined in. Not on parent or child contexts. Hence you need to register it in both contexts.

There is one drawback of having 2 the same `<context:property-placeholder />` both will load the same resource and you endup loading the same properties file twice. To eliminate this combine the `<context:property-placeholder />` with a `<util:properties />` element. The latter loads properties file(s) and exposes them as bean in the context, you can wire this bean to the `<context:property-placeholder />` using the `properties-ref` attribute. You only load the properties in the root context and simple refer to them in child contexts.

**Root Context**

```
<util:properties id="appProperties" location="classpath:default.properties, file:///etc/gallery/gallery.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="appProperties" />
```

**Child Context**

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="appProperties" />
```

### `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Regarding the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` that registers, amongst others, a `RequestMappingHandlerMapper`, this bean is responsible for detecting methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` in `@Controller` annotated classes. By default it does this in the `ApplicationContext` it is defined in NOT in parent contexts. You could set the [`detectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.html#setDetectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts-boolean-) property to `true` to make this happen.

As a rule of thumb you could say that your root context should contain everything application global like services, repositories, infrastructure beans like datasources etc. The child contexts (loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` should only contain web related materials like `@Controllers`.).

Just copy pasting the `<context:component-scan />`, literally duplicating it, is a bad (very bad) idea. As this will lead to instantiate all your beans twice and might lead to issues with transactions, memory etc. Because things like `<tx:annotation-driven />` work with AOP and AOP is also applied using a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and `BeanPostProcessor` just like the property support.

**Root Context**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject">
    <context:exclude-filters type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

**Child Context**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filters type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Thank you, that clears away some of the haze.  Regarding `property-placeholder`, does that mean there will be two sets of properties in memory?  Is there a way to load them once and share the collection among all contexts?  Also, thanks for confirming that duplicating `component-scan` is a bad idea.  I thought that was the case but couldn't find anything in the docs to suggest it.

Comment: I've added some information regarding the property placeholder and added some sample config for clarification.

Comment: Perfect! It's all starting to make sense now, thank you.